# find a 99% confidence interval given &sum;<sub>i=1</sub><sup>61</sup> X_i = 6450 and &sum;<sub>i=1</sub><sup>61</sup> X^2_i = 6450

Tags: statistics, variance, confidence-interval

find a 99% confidence interval for the mean given:

∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>61</sup> X_i = 6450

and

∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>61</sup> X^2_i = 6450

I found the sample mean of 105.7377 . (6450/61)

I do not know how to find the variance. Then confidence interval is computable.

Comment: We use a form of $\LaTeX$ here called MathJax. It works in the title section too.

Answer (score 1):

CI for mean or which? You can use those formulas to find the sample variance too.

$s^{2}= \frac{\sum_{i=0}^n x^{2}_{i} - (\sum_{i=0}^n x_{i})^{2}/n}{n-1} $

If for mean you will use a T-interval

$(\bar{x} - t_{\alpha/2,df}{\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}},\bar{x} + t_{\alpha/2,df}{\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}) $

where df=n-1

Comment: yes, for the mean

Comment: if you are allowed to use a graphing calculator a ti-84 can do it